# insert string to oracle with line feed and carriage return. by c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I try to insert string by c# code to oracle ,
but when I get it back to my code it comes without line feed and carriage return, 
and without more special characters ( like ! ( ) ; & )
I want it come back as it send.
I try to replace '\r\n' to char(10) char(13) , but it didn't work.
Thx!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please show your work.. Read [FAQ] and [ask] also..

Answer (score 1):

You DO get the data back as sent.

`\n` is just the Visual Studio representation for a line feed. That is how the debugger / IDE shows a line feed.

So...

- `\n` (in C#/Visual Studio/Debugger) = ASCII 10 = LineFeed.
- `\r` (in C#/Visual Studio/Debugger) = ASCII 13 = Carriage Return.

Thus `"Hello\r\nGood bye"` is the same thing as `"Hello" + (char)10 + (char)13 + "Good bye"`.
etc.

Comment: yes, you are right . I  am looking for  the oracle representation for a line feed